# how to use props in a "depth 2" hierarchy

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to use the props of the App.js file into **DishDetailComponent.js** but i have other component in the medium of these two, the assigment say:

- In this task you will be adding a new DishdetailComponent to your React application and include the component into the menu component's view so that the details of a specific dish are displayed there:
- Replace the card showing the selected dish in MenuComponent's view with the DishdetailComponent, and make sure to pass the selected dish information as props to the DishdetailComponent.
- Create a new DishDetail class in a file named DishdetailComponent.js in the components folder
  Export the DishDetail class from this file so that it can be imported in MenuComponent.js and used to construct the view of the selected dish.
- Return a  from the render() function. This  should use the Bootstrap row class to position the content within the . This div will display both the details of the dish in a Card and the list of comments side-by-side for medium to extra large screens, but will stack them for xs and sm screens.
  The card should be enclosed inside a  appropriate Bootstrap column classes so that it occupies the entire 12 columns for the xs and sm screen sizes, and 5 columns for md screens and above. Also apply a class of m-1 to this div.
- The comments should be enclosed in a  to which you apply appropriate column classes so that it occupies the entire 12 columns for the xs and sm screen sizes, and 5 columns for md screens and above. Also apply a class of m-1 to this div.
- If the dish is null then you should return an empty

App.js

```
import MenuComponent from './component/MenuComponent'

import './App.css';
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Navbar dark color="primary">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">
              Ristorante Con Fusion
          </NavbarBrand>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
        <MenuComponent
          dishes={this.state.dishes}
        />


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

MenuComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

/* Components */
import DishDetail from './DishDetailComponent'

class MenuComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedDish: null
        };
        console.log('Menu Component constructor is invoked');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Menu Component componentDidMount is invoked')
    }

    onDishSelect(dish) {
        this.setState({ selectedDish: dish });
    }

    renderDish(dish) {
        if (dish != null) {
            return (
                <Card >
                    <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                        <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }


    render() {
        const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => { /* This is a prop that are provided from App.js 
            in the render() <MenuComponent dishes={}> */
            return (
                <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <Card onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
                        <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                        <CardImgOverlay>
                            <CardTitle><strong>{dish.name}</strong></CardTitle>
                        </CardImgOverlay>
                    </Card>
                </div>
            );
        });



        console.log('Menu component render is invoked')

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {menu}
                </div>
              
                <div className="row col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5 mr-1">
                    <div>
                        <Card className="">
                            {this.renderDish(this.state.selectedDish)}
                        </Card>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MenuComponent;
```

DishDetailComponent.js

```
/* Modules */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, CardImg } from 'reactstrap';
/* Components */
/* Styles */



class DishDetailComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    onDishSelect(dish) {
        this.setState({ selectedDish: dish })
    }

    renderDish(dish) {
        if (dish != null) {
            return (
                <Card >
                    <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                        <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }



    render() {

        const comment = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return ( 
                <div key={dish.key}>
                    <ul className="unorder-list">
                        {dish.comments}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
        })

        return (
            <div className="row col-12 col-lg-5 m-1">
                <Card >
                  HEre i have to put the info the name the img and these things 
                </Card>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default DishDetailComponent;
```

This is the last component im tried to do it but i dont know how to use very well props!

if you want see my git https://gitlab.com/folayao/react-coursera-felipe

Comment: The question in the React eco system that lead to the cancer Redux becoming so popular.

Comment: And the problem! i cant use redux for now!